# Why does complete() create duplicate rows in my data?

Tags: r, tidyr

When I use the complete() function to fill in rows in my data that have no cases I find it is creating many duplicate rows as well. These can be removed with the unique() function, but I want to understand how I can avoid generating all these extra rows in the first place.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# An incomplete table
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs, cyl) %>% 
  count()

# complete() creates a table with many duplicate rows
temp <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs, cyl) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  complete(vs = c(0, 1), cyl = c(4, 6, 8), fill = list(n = 0)) 

unique(temp)
```

Comment: I think this is because your dataset is grouped.  Try ungrouping via `ungroup` prior to `complete`. [This github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/396) may be somewhat relevant.

Comment: Thank you @aosmith, that was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is answered in a comment by @aosmith.

The duplicates come from the grouped data. Ungrouping using `ungroup` solves the issue:

```
temp <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs, cyl) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(vs = c(0, 1), cyl = c(4, 6, 8), fill = list(n = 0))
```