# Dataframe is too big for supercomputer

Tags: r, dplyr, sparse-matrix, large-data

I am trying to create a matrix of donors and recipients, populated with the sum of donations produced in each couple keeping the eventual NAs.

It works well for small datasets (See toy example below) but when I switch to national datasets (3m entries) several problems emerge: besides being painstakingly slow, the creation of the fill df consume all the memory of the (super)computer and I get the error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1529.0 Gb"

How should I tackle the problem?
Thanks a lot!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
libray(bigmemory)

candidate_id <- c("cand_1","cand_1","cand_1","cand_2","cand_3")
donor_id <- c("don_1","don_1","don_2","don_2","don_3")
donation <- c(1,2,3.5,4,10)
df = data.frame(candidate_id,donor_id,donation)
colnames(df) <- c("candidate_id","donor_id","donation")

fill <- df %>% 
  group_by(df$candidate_id,df$donor_id) %>% 
  summarise(tot_donation=sum(as.numeric(donation))) %>%
  complete(df$candidate_id,df$donor_id)

fill <- unique(fill[ ,1:3])
colnames(fill) <- c("candidate_id","donor_id","tot_donation")

nrow = length(unique(df$candidate_id))
ncol = length(unique(df$donor_id))
row_names = unique(fill$candidate_id)
col_names = unique(fill$donor_id)

x <- big.matrix(nrow, ncol, init=NA,dimnames=list(row_names,col_names))

for (i in 1:nrow){
  for (j in 1:ncol){

    x[i,j] <- fill[which(fill$candidate_id == row_names[i] & 
                       fill$donor_id == col_names[j]), 3]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using `unique` because your output has duplicated values.
Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573217/why-does-complete-create-duplicate-rows-in-my-data),
you should try the following in order to avoid duplication:

```
fill <- df %>% 
    group_by(candidate_id, donor_id) %>% 
    summarise(tot_donation=sum(donation)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    complete(candidate_id, donor_id)
```

Can you then try to create your desired output?
I think `unique` can be very resource-heavy,
so try to avoid calling it.
The `tidyr` version of what Benjamin suggested should be:

```
spread(fill, donor_id, tot_donation)
```

EDIT: By the way, since you tagged the question with `sparse-matrix`,
you could indeed use sparsity to your advantage:

```
library(Matrix)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  candidate_id = c("cand_1","cand_1","cand_1","cand_2","cand_3"),
  donor_id = c("don_1","don_1","don_2","don_2","don_3"),
  donation = c(1,2,3.5,4,10)
)

summ <- df %>% 
    group_by(candidate_id, donor_id) %>% 
    summarise(tot_donation=sum(donation)) %>%
    ungroup

num_candidates <- nlevels(df$candidate_id)
num_donors <- nlevels(df$donor_id)
smat <- Matrix(0, num_candidates, num_donors, sparse = TRUE, dimnames = list(
  levels(df$candidate_id),
  levels(df$donor_id)
))

indices <- summ %>%
  select(candidate_id, donor_id) %>%
  mutate_all(unclass) %>%
  as.matrix

smat[indices] <- summ$tot_donation
smat

3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
       don_1 don_2 don_3
cand_1     3   3.5     .
cand_2     .   4.0     .
cand_3     .   .      10
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(fill, candidate_id ~ donor_id, 
          value.var = "tot_donation", 
          fun.aggregate = sum)
```

I don't know if it will avoid the memory issue, but it will likely be much faster than a double `for` loop.

I have to run to a meeting, but part of me wonders if there is a way to do this with `outer`.

Comment: The suggestion greatly improves the speed of the matrix population, but does not improve the construction of the fill database that still crashes. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: Maybe give [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Presentations) a try?